# Adding new form when clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

When the user clicks at the "Add New Job" link, a new form containing three fields will appear. That's the main form:

```
<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE 1</h2>
<div class="job-content">
  <input type="text" value="Company" name="company" />
  <input type="text" value="Course" name="course" />
  <input type="date" value="Date" name="date" />
</div>

<h1><a href="add-new-form">ADD NEW JOB +</a></h1>
//When clicked, it will show another form, with the same fields from the form above. 

<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE 2</h2>
<div class="job-content">
  <input type="text" value="Company" name="company2" />
  <input type="text" value="Course" name="course2" />
  <input type="date" value="Date" name="date2" />
</div>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: any trial code snippet......done by you

Comment: Do you need new forms on each click or you would like to use one form and specify HTML elements as array?

Comment: New forms on each click. I hve done this so far, but still no success:

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add-new-job").click( function() {
$("#nameFields").append('<input type="text" name="company[]" value="Company" />');
});
});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.clone()` to copy the original `.job-content` and then increment the form item names to replicate your example output.

This will also allow you to expand on the number of inputs if needed in the future without updating your JavaScript code.

```
$(function () {
    var duplicates = 0,
        $original = $('.job-content').clone(true);

    function DuplicateForm () {
        var newForm;

        duplicates++; 

        newForm = $original.clone(true).insertBefore($('h1'));

        $.each($('input', newForm), function(i, item) {            
            $(item).attr('name', $(item).attr('name') + duplicates);
        });

        $('<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE ' + (duplicates + 1) + '</h2>').insertBefore(newForm);
    }

    $('a[href="add-new-form"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        DuplicateForm();
    });
});
```

Working example - **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbc6J/3/)**

***Updated** to clone the original `job-content` on page load so original form values are preserved.*

Comment: I see. This will clone the div every time I click at ADD A JOB, or only once?

Comment: @Anna it will make a clone of the original, update it, and then add it to the page each time you click ADD A JOB. Please view the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vbc6J/2/ - to see it working.

Comment: Jonathan, it did the job. I'm trying to figure out how I would record the fields in database, but I think I'll perform another question. Sorry for the delay to reply. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

```
It will add more form if u click "ADD NEW JOB +";

<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE 1</h2>
<div class="job-content">
  <input type="text" value="Company" name="company" />
  <input type="text" value="Course" name="course" />
  <input type="date" value="Date" name="date" />
</div>
<div id="concat"></div>
<h1><a href="javascript:;" id="addfield">ADD NEW JOB +</a></h1>

<script>    
$("#addfield").click(function(){

var detailContent = '<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE 1</h2>
                     <div class="job-content">
  <input type="text" value="Company" name="company" />
  <input type="text" value="Course" name="course" />
  <input type="date" value="Date" name="date" />
</div>';    

$('#concat').append(detailContent); 

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Get it done already. Sorry for the delay to reply. Thankyou for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2JgtT/

Note: you need somekind of logic to add more than 2 job fields.. this is just a sample.

HTML:

```
<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE 1</h2>

<div class="job-content">
    <input type="text" value="Company" name="company" />
    <input type="text" value="Course" name="course" />
    <input type="date" value="Date" name="date" />
</div>
<div class="jobfields">

<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE 2</h2>

    <div class="job-content">
        <input type="text" value="Company" name="company2" />
        <input type="text" value="Course" name="course2" />
        <input type="date" value="Date" name="date2" />
    </div>
</div>

<h1><a href="add-new-form" class="addjob">ADD NEW JOB +</a></h1>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".addjob", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.job-content').next('.jobfields').show();
});
```

OR this may be: http://jsfiddle.net/2JgtT/3/  look at the html, i have wrapped the divs in container

```
$(document).on("click", ".addjob", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addJobField();
});

function addJobField() {
    $('.container').append("<div class='job-content'> " +
        "<input type='text' value='Company' name='company' />" +
        "<input type='text' value='Course' name='course' /> " +
        "<input type='date' value='Date' name='date' /> </div>");
}
```

Comment: Get it done already. Sorry for the delay to reply. Thankyou for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery append method when the Button is clicked using click event

```
$('#id').click(function() {
var x=$("#formid").html();

$("body").append(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="" id="test">test</a>
<div id="test1"></div>
<script>    
$("#test").click(function(){

    var detailContent = '<div>what portion need to add there</div>';    

    $('#test1').append(detailContent); 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edited HTML:

```
<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE 1</h2>

<div class="job-content">
    <input type="text" value="Company" name="company" />
    <input type="text" value="Course" name="course" />
    <input type="date" value="Date" name="date" />
</div>

<h1 id="add_job"><a href="add-new-form" onclick="return false;">ADD NEW JOB +</a></h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
var i = 1;
$("#add_job").click(function() {
    $("body").append("<h2>JOB EXPERIENCE "+ ++i + "</h2>");
    $("body").append($(".job-content:nth-child(2)").clone());
});
```

**HTML Explanation:**

Nothing much edited but on the click of the hyperlink I made sure that it should return false or else it would link to another page.

---

**JavaScript Explanation:**

First I set a variable to one which is the number of job experiences that will be incremented every time the button is clicked. Then on the click of the `h1` of the link I append two things in the body. The first is the `h2` which is the heading for the job experiences and the second thing is the copy of the first form that is present already their.

Comment: Get it done already. Sorry for the delay to reply. Thankyou for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

A quick JQuery solution:

```
$("#add-new-form").on("click",function{
   var form = '<form>
               <div class="job-content">
                 <input type="text" value="Company" name="company" />
                 <input type="text" value="Course" name="course" />
                 <input type="date" value="Date" name="date" />
               </div>
               </form>';
   $('body').append(form);
});
```

I have no means of testing but is this like something you were looking for?

Comment: You can directly get the html content .. here no need to type entire form to the form variable.. use all resources .. minimize code lines.